# Symfony write process output to file

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, phpunit, symfony-process

How to write the output of an Asynchronous process to the file. I have the following code in my phpunit bootstrap file:

```
$command = 'exec php ' . $kernel->getRootDir() . '/console '
            . 'xxx:servicebus:start-services --env='
            . $kernel->getEnvironment();

$servicebusCommand = new Symfony\Component\Process\Process($command);
$servicebusCommand->start();
```

Obviously the code starts a servicebus instance which listens to all the incoming requests to the server. Once the tests are ran, the requests go to the servicebus and it stuck there. I need to see the output of the start servicebus command to see what went wrong.

Any idea how to write the output of the process to some log file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$servicebusCommand->getIncrementalErrorOutput()` and `$servicebusCommand->getIncrementalOutput()` regularly.

Comment: Thanks! would you mind explaining 'regularly' a bit more? I start the process in my bootstrap, and after the process starts, the execution of the bootstrap script terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass closure to the start or run function

```
$process->start(function ($type, $buffer) use ($logFile) {
        file_put_contents($logFile, $buffer, FILE_APPEND);
    
        if ('err' === $type) {
                echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
        } else {
                echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
        }
});
```

[From here](https://gonzalo123.com/2012/10/08/how-to-send-the-output-of-symfonys-process-component-to-a-node-js-server-in-real-time-with-socket-io/)